# How to uninstall a which did not get installed properly

Tags: system-installation, sudo

when I tried to install dropbox it did not get installed properly it now only shows the icon and does not work too so I want to uninstall it if I do it using gui nothing happens and it is still there if I do it using terminal it shows this

```
sairamakrishna@Krishna:~$ sudo apt-get remove dropbox
[sudo] password for sairamakrishna: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappindicator1 libindicator7 linux-headers-3.13.0-32
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-46
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-49
  linux-headers-3.13.0-49-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-51
  linux-headers-3.13.0-51-generic linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dropbox
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
sairamakrishna@Krishna:~$ ^C
sairamakrishna@Krishna:~$
```

so even after this the program is still there 
Please help me how to uninstall it

Answer (score 0):

Run those commands:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove dropbox
```